# URL optional parameter is taking "," by default

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

Hi I have implemented web api controller as like below..

```
[HttpGet("{xyz}/{reason?}")]
public asyncHttpGet([FromRoute] string xyz,string reason=null)
{
    // implementation code here
}
```

if i am calling from swaggerUI by default optional parameter is taking "," . why it is taking comma. Is there any specific reason?. It is working fine while calling from postman tool.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Is taking , by default"?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama: If i am not passing optional parameter value by default it is considering " ,  " . as value.

Comment: Just so we're clear: are you saying that the variable `reason` holds a `","` if called from Swagger?

Comment: ProgrammingLlama : Yes..

Comment: What does the request that Swagger is making look like if you look at it in your browser's debugger?

Comment: Post the CURL generated by swagger please

Comment: @fbv below is the CURL request

curl -X "Get" \

' https://localhost/search/2355555/, ' \

-H: ' accept:*/* ' \

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/issues/1708

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama , So it is an issue at swagger-js side. how to rectify issue in code then.